# Show error message for wrong password

Tags: asp.net

I have this login code and I want to show (error message "Invalid User&Password") If someone input a wrong password, currently right now my code is just redirecting to same page if error occur.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l,string ReturnUrl="")
    {
        using (graceEntities dc = new graceEntities())
        {
            var user = dc.tbl_User.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(l.Username) && a.Password.Equals(l.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,l.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Main");
                }
            }


        }


        ModelState.Remove("Pasword");
            return View();
    }
```

Comment: You need to put that code in your else
    if (user != null){ ...  } else { ...here.. }

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case where the user is not found in the database. Please read the comments inline in code below for further clarification:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Login model, string ReturnUrl = "")
{
    // 1. Do validation and return view if validation errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // 2. No validation error so search db for user 
    using (graceEntities dc = new graceEntities())
    {
        var user = dc.tbl_User
            .Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(model.Username) &&
            a.Password.Equals(model.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
            }

            // No return url, redirect to main/index
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
        }
    }


    // 3. We made it here, so user was not found
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate Your Help!